# How to select an element with dynamic selector?

Tags: javascript, css, web-scraping, css-selectors, puppeteer

I want to select a selector using puppeteer and css selectors. The element only has an id. The id is changing everytime i browse the site.

```
<span id="select-fjva-container">Text</span>
```

'fjva' is changing everytime i browse the site. So it could be something like 'abc' or 'xyz' on the next browsing. The chars in the middle are totaly random.

Is there a way how i could select it?

I would think of:

```
const select = document.querySelector('#select2-*-container')
```

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 2):

You can select all elements whose `id` starts with `select`, then loop through the elements and check the parts:

```js
const startsWith = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=select]')
startsWith.forEach(elem => {
  const parts = elem.id.split("-")
  if(parts[0] == "select" && parts[2] == "container") console.log(elem)
})
```

```html
<span id="select-abc-container">Correct</span>
<span id="select-def-container">Correct</span>
<span id="select-geh-container">Correct</span>
<span id="select-container">Wrong</span>
```

Although [David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas)'s suggestion to use the starts with & ends with selector is indeed more clever:

```js
const startsWith = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=select-][id$=-container]')
startsWith.forEach(elem => {
  console.log(elem)
})
```

```html
<span id="select-abc-container">Correct</span>
<span id="select-def-container">Correct</span>
<span id="select-geh-container">Correct</span>
```

<sup>Take note that the above selector will also select elements with class `select-container`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple one-line selector - all those ids starting with 'select-' and ending with '-container (this snippet also assumes you want to not select 'select-container' but just drop the :not part if you do want to select it):

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('span[id^="select-"][id$="-container"]:not(#select-container)');
for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
}
```

```html
<span id="select-fjva-container">Text</span>
<span id="select--container">Text</span>
<span id="select-container">Text</span>
```